# Can VHDL synthesize clk'event?

Tags: vhdl, synthesis

I'm trying to write a 4-bit multiplier with VHDL. This is the code I wrote:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity multiplier_8bit_2 is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Y : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end multiplier_8bit_2;

architecture Behavioral of multiplier_8bit_2 is

begin
process(clk, A, B)
    variable sum_result : unsigned(8 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if A'event or B'event then
        sum_result:=(others => '0');
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            if B(i)='1' then
                sum_result:=sum_result+shift_left(b"00000"&unsigned(A),i);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end if;
    Y<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sum_result(7 downto 0));
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

It can be executed in simulation and it works, but when I try to synthesize it, I get:
unsupported Clock statement.

Comment: Commonly you cannot synthesize `X'event` because the target logic does not provide such circuitry. Anyway, your process does not use `clk`. Aren't you supposed to use its raising (or falling) edge to calculate the result?

Comment: No, it's not necessary in my project! But the point is, I want multiplication to be executed when a or b changes.

Comment: Since you cannot use `X'event` in synthesis, use combinatorial logic without it. Your process already has `A` and `B` in its sensitivity list, so I assume no problem with simulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a multiplier with 4 bit arguments, then code it without clk as follows.  You do not need a'event or b'event.

```
process(A, B)
    variable sum_result : unsigned(8 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    sum_result:=(others => '0');
    for i in 0 to 3 loop
        if B(i)='1' then
           sum_result:=sum_result+shift_left(b"00000"&unsigned(A),i);
        end if;
    end loop;
    Y<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sum_result(7 downto 0));
end process;
```

OTOH, if you wanted a multiplier and a flip-flop, then code the following.   You have no need for A or B on the sensitivity list.

```
process(clk)
    variable sum_result : unsigned(8 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    if clk = '1' and clk'event then
        sum_result:=(others => '0');
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            if B(i)='1' then
                sum_result:=sum_result+shift_left(b"00000"&unsigned(A),i);
            end if;
        end loop;
        Y<=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(sum_result(7 downto 0));
    end if;
end process;
```